# Why charging state of the phone affects my app's behavior

Tags: android, postdelayed

I have a `Runnable r` that is triggered periodically once per minute by  `handler.postDelayed(60*1000)`. And I test my code on a real device.

However I notice, when the phone is charging (AC or USB) , it works well, but if the phone is disconnected, the `Runnable r` will only run once every 20min or even worse, several hours. Thanks for any help!

Below is the code:

```
private final Runnable listen_to_server = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {

                    handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage(PING_SERVER,"listen"));
                    synchronized (listen) {
                        listen.wait();
                    }
                    handler.postDelayed(listen_to_server, 50000);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }.start();
    }
};
```

In the Handler:

```
    handler=new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(final Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case PING_SERVER:
                    String type = (String) msg.obj;
                    add_log("ping server"); // print to screen and Log.d
                    ...
                    ...
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: post your runnable code and how you are calling it

Comment: can you post some code please?

Comment: Your phone probably goes into deep sleep mode to save battery when it's not connected via USB and the screen is off. AFAIK timers won't be updated at all / not as often while in deep sleep.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will a Handler postDelayed not being fired when CPU sleeps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17324587/will-a-handler-postdelayed-not-being-fired-when-cpu-sleeps)

Comment: @Michael  Maybe this is the case, but how could I solve this problem. I do not want it go to sleep

Comment: @Michael Is there a way (by code) that I can prevent my phone from sleeping, or pretend that it is charging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28878673/handler-postdelayed-running-for-extra-time) i think the problem might be, as they said:

> Android is not a real-time operating system. All postDelayed()
>   guarantees is that it will be at least the number of milliseconds
>   specified. Beyond that will be dependent primarily on what the main
>   application thread is doing (if you are tying it up, it cannot process
>   the Runnable), and secondarily on what else is going on the device
>   (services run with background priority and therefore get less CPU time
>   than does the foreground).

How to fix this? in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824912/handler-postdelayed-delayed-longer-as-configured/5825063#5825063) post the solution was the following:

> You'll probably have better luck using the AlarmManager for such a
>   long delay. Handler is best for ticks and timeouts while your app is
>   in the foreground.

so try implement an AlarmManager looking at [the doc.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

Hope i helped :)

Comment: Thanks for the link. But my app is indeed in foreground -- I have even killed  all other apps -- and I wish to leave my app on for hours, with the runnable runs once per minute

Comment: @ZhangYifan You tryed using a service?

Comment: anyway, not sure, but is it correct the Runnable's syntax? i think before Run you need @Override and after it you don't need the "new Thread(){". Maybe i'm wrong, don't know

Comment: Maybe i will try using a service later... I need new Thread() in runnable as it needs to do network stuff which could not be on the main thread. Thanks for the @Override :)  but that seems not mandated.

Comment: @ZhangYifan sorry but i don't know what else to do, maybe someone can help you more :)